# Имя столбца с ключом

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Всем привет. Вопрос, как в таблице получить имя колонки(столбца), которая является ключом в данной таблице? (MySql)

Comment: [Information schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/8.0/en/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.